# Error in SLA engine while calculating the Resolve By field

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2013

We have very strange bug in our MS Dynamics CRM 2013 caused by SLA.
We've got a single default SLA on our on-premise organization, with associated business hours. 
Simple 9:00 - 18:00 working week from Monday till Friday. The only thing it calculates is Resolve By field. SLA works fine from Monday till Friday. But on weekends I have thousands of errors from our integration modules caused by timeouts and freezing of some plugin.

> [10] ERROR Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException: An error occured while processing this request. ---> System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.4375115. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'https://server.com/orgname/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:02:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The second one is

> [11] ERROR Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException: An error occured while processing this request. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: There is no active transaction. This error is usually caused by custom plug-ins that ignore errors from service calls and continue processing.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

First of all we have changed timeouts in integration modules from default to over 10 minutes and tried to find the reason of these errors. 
After short researching I found this [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Plugin - There is no active transaction error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755770/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-plugin-there-is-no-active-transaction-error), but it is not helpfull for us. 
Integration modules create "Incidents" in our CRM and the only thing we have on Incident creation is SLA. So this week after first error I tried to disable SLA and there were no errors after this. I have no ideas what is going wrong and how I could solve this issue. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

couple of areas of suspects, but not clearly able to reach to the point to understand whats going on...

1. Is your Integration module trying to update incident entity which might involve triggering SLA process and might introduce creating or updating any specific related entities ?
2. Are there any weekly Jobs running against incidents for updates ?
3. Any update plugins or workflows registered against incidents?
4. Are there lot of processes/workflows in waiting state ?

could be SLA logic which has lot of wait times etc...

Comment: 1. My Integration module only creates incidents.
2. No weekly jobs.
3. No plugins and workflows registered against these entities.
4. Only SLA workflows and SLA logic is not very complex. 

Thanks for reply.